# Is there a web application that puts a white Polaroid-border on images?

Tags: webapp-rec

Does anyone know of a **free web application** that allows you to upload images and turn them into **Polaroid-looking pictures**, i.e.:

- apply white border
- tilt slightly
- apply subtle shadow

something like these:

[image: 'Polaroid' images]

## Addendum

Thanks @user5821, with [Picasa Web](http://picasaweb.google.com) I was able to make this in five minutes:

[image: image example]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use Picasa (and Picasaweb), you can do this to any of your photos by clicking "Edit", which opens the picnik editor. Click the "Create" tab, click "Frames" in the toolbar, and scroll down to "Poloroid".

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find a free service TUXPI here: http://www.tuxpi.com/photo-effects/photo-paper

Picasa will work too, though this tool seems to be specifically focused on what you're looking for.